# 【Ubuntu 16.04.2】Hang in Apple MacPro 1,1 only at restart

Tags: 16.04, server, mac

I slipped a bit and purchased MacPro 1, 1.

In order to use this as a server, I installed Ubuntu Server.
I tried executing the reboot command, but after shutting down, it does not shift to the startup sequence just by sound like a seek sound of the HDD.
Ctrl + Alt + Delete also did not work.

How do I set it up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"
```